# Query and export from unsortable table SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

First I am sorry for my bad English,  is not my language.

My problem is: I have a table with around 10 million records of transaction of bank. It don't have PK and didn't sort as any column.

My work is create a page to filter and export it to csv. But limit of rows to export Csv is around 200k records.

I have some idea like:

- create 800 tables of 800 ATMs (just an idea, I know it's stupid) and send data from main table to it 1 time per day => export to 800 file csv
- use Linq to get 100k record per time then next time, I skip those. But I am stuck when `Skip` command need `OrderBy` and I got `OutOfMemoryException` with it

  ```
  db.tblEJTransactions.OrderBy(u => u.Id).Take(100000).ToList()
  ```

Can anyone help me, every idea is welcome (my boss said I can use anything includes create hundred of tables, use Nosql ... )

Comment: _There's no CSV row limit_. There is an Excel row limit, and Excel is usually used to open CSV. If you're talking about a web page that allows you to download 200,000 records, you might have other problems like bandwidth. What can anyone do with 200K arbitrary records in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a primary key in your table, then add one.
The simplest and easiest is to add an `int IDENTITY` column.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T 
ADD ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)

ALTER TABLE dbo.T 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_T PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
```

If you can't alter the original table, create a copy.

Once the table has a primary key you can sort by it and select chunks/pages of 200K rows with predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about my solution. But you can refer and try it:

```
select top 1000000 *, row_number() over (order by (select null)) from tblEJTransactions
```

The above query returns sorted list.

And then you can use Linq to get the result.